# Extract multiple (and potentially unlimited) params from an URL for .htaccess redirect

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am writing a mod_rewrite redirect that essentially grabs all the different parameters from an old URL format and pass them all concatenated as one argument to the new url.

Eg.:

Old URL: `/rss.php/searchtype/basic/yearfrom/PARAM1/colour/PARAM2/yearto/PARAM3/` .. and so on.

New URL: `/search/keywords/PARAM1+PARAM2+PARAM3`

So basically I need to be able to match the start of the string, but after that match the VALUE of any argueent passed and then append them to the end of the new URL with a space between them.

Comment: Yeah it's the concatenation of them at the other end of the string which may be impossible

Comment: Are the identifiers that appear before PARAMS predefined ? or Is there any pattern of the PARAMS ( only numbers / bools something) ? Regex will find it hard to pick the Params without any concrete pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to extract the params, no problem.

But once they're extracted, the problem is that you want to concatenate them without `yearfrom` (and so on)...

I don't think this is possible, and what I'm pretty sure is not possible, is that you want to replace chars (replace **`/`** by **`+`**).

This is an answer even though it may disappoint you (sorry).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RewriteMap` with an external program to do this. See [Apache Docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.3/rewrite/rewritemap.html) and this [RewriteMap example from Rick Bowen](http://onlamp.com/pub/a/apache/2005/04/28/apacheckbk.html)